# Диагностировать циклическую переадресацию

Tags: apache, редирект, mod-rewrite

После подключения mod_rewrite в apache на сайте возникла циклическая переадресация, любая страница редиректит на саму же себя.

- файл .htaccess особо роли не играет, переадресовывает даже без него
- переадресовывает даже при запросе к статическим файлам
- есть аж 4 узла, которые могут являться причиной: кэш браузера, cloudflare, apache, мой сайт. С последним маловероятно.
- error.log не показывает ничего характерного.

В CloudFlare стоит принудительное перенаправление на https со всех страниц. На самом сервере SSL еще не установлен, то есть проксирование происходит по схеме cloudflare https -> server http. Возможно эта информация поможет.

Куда копать?

Comment: `После подключения mod_rewrite` / `файл .htaccess особо роли не играет` Никакого противоречия? Смотрите тогда прямо в virtualhost

Comment: Что там может быть такого, имеющее отношение к переадресации?

Comment: Например, RewriteRule?

Comment: Нет там такого.